# Accessing apache2.4 server through WiFi / WLAN inside home network

Tags: apache, wifi, private-network

I have netgear 1500 wifi DSL router having private IP 192.168.1.1. I am running apache 2.4 in my desktop PC having IP 192.168.1.2 and my laptop has an IP 192.168.1.3. While I try to access the apache server as http://192.168.1.2:80/index.html I get a message requested URL /index.html not found, while it shows up properly when I access is as localhost.
I have done port forwarding for port:80 and firewalls are stopped.
I have quickheal running in the same machine in which apache runs. Both machines are windows.

What do I need to do so that I can access the server from my laptop?

I have added the privileges through http.conf also.

I see another problem - when I ping the desktop machine, which runs the server, the request is timed out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. Skype and antivirus are using port 80. Making apache listen to other port - like 8080 solved the problem.

I learned that apache "**does not**" share a port with other applications.

Hope someone else might be helped from this.

Sukalyan